# Styling HTML checkboxes with images

Tags: jquery, css, checkbox

I want to add an image to the checkbox... That is if it is selected tick mark (I have image) should be shown. else cross image should be shown... Is this possible using CSS or using jQuery? Please provide me link that guide me.

Answer (score 2):

You can do this with CSS and some JS:

http://ryanfait.com/resources/custom-checkboxes-and-radio-buttons/

Answer (score 0):

its imposible with css, you have to use any plugin

for example, with the example of @mr-pallazzo and changing the image, with your own image

Answer (score 0):

You might like to try:

1. http://widowmaker.kiev.ua/checkbox/
2. http://boedesign.com/blog/2008/06/08/imagetick-for-jquery/
3. http://aaronweyenberg.com/90/pretty-checkboxes-with-jquery

First one seems quite useful :)

Third one is pretty (if I can say that about code)